# Send non-stringified objects with fetch

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise, form-data, fetch-api

I'm using the `fetch`-api for the first time and having trouble passing a non-stringified `JSON` objects to the server. 
Basically I want to achieve the same behavior as this:

```
$.post(url, {"test": "test"}, function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

The fetch method is communicating with an web API which is *unaccessable* for me and **expects a plain `JSON` object**.

Normally I would just use `FormData` to pass data to the server, however the `JSON` will be transformed to a string `[Object object]`:

```
fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: {"test": "test"}
})
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json))
   .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

The body request seems to be empty when using `$_POST` (which is what the API is using), though gives the right value when using `file_get_contents('php://input)`.

I though this had something to do with the wrong `header` given to the request. So I tried to add the header Ajax post uses: `content-type:multipart/form-data;`. However, this also did not get any value.

I was wondering if this was explicity intentional to not use plain `JSON` object to give as data, or that I'm simply missing something?

---

This does work, but is not allowed as it is a stringify version of the `JSON` object:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));

fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
})
   .then(data => data.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json))
   .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `body: JSON.stringify(data)` since *JSON* is just a single string value anyway. It's not really an `object` as such

Comment: @CodingIntrigue It seems that when I do not use `formData` it does not work with `$_POST`. That's why I thought `fetch-api` is automatically settings headers when using the `formData` object, but I have no idea which.

Comment: Uh, your `$.post` snippet doesn't send JSON either?

Comment: @Bergi You mean `{test: 'test'}` should become `{"test": "test"}`? Updated that :P

Comment: @nkmol: No, I mean that `$.post` sends the request with a content-type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. Your objects is sent through [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to become "`test=test`", not through `JSON.stringify` to become "`{"test":"test"}`".

Comment: @Bergi Wow, that was it... `body: $.param(data)` and setting the right header fixed it. down-side of just using the `jQuery` variant, never considered what happened under the hood. If you want, you can change your comment in an answer and I'll gladly accept it ^^ Thanks again!

Comment: You don't send JSON, but the question is about JSON. So if you write JSON you don't mean JSON? I'm confused.

Comment: @zeroflagL I had no idea `$.post` wasn't sending JSON. But as @Bergi explained, it does not send JSON, but just the parameters. I basically wanted the same behaviour as `$.post` where PHP could retrieve it with `$_POST`. I fixed this now, not sure if I should write my own answers as @Bergi basically told me the answer :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So firstly, I need to post to the POST-protocol, which is used by `$_POST`. I do this by adding a header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which is the protocol used by `$_POST`, as described in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)) to the fetch post request:

```
fetch(url, {
   headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}), // Default header which $_POST listens to
   ...
```

Now the way `$.post` actually sends data is by creating a serialized string (eg: `a%5Bone%5D=1`) of the given object. To transform an object to a serialized string, you can use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/):

```
fetch(url, {
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}), // Default header which $_POST listens to
            method: 'POST',
            body: $.param(data)
        })
```

This will make you able to retreive data from `$_POST` like you would do with a simple `$.post`.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is inside a variable `var data = { a: "some data", b: 123 }`. If you want your code in PHP to access these fields this way:

```
$_POST["a"] == "some data";
$_POST["b"] == 123;
```

Then you need to send the data in the `formData` format this way:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('a', 'some data');
fdata.append('b', '123');
```

Now you can send that data and PHP will have access to separated fields `a` and `b` but notice `b` will be a string, not a number.

What if you want to send an array. Let's say `{ c: ['hello', 'world', '!'] }`? You must follow PHP name conventions and add the same name multiple times:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('c[]', 'hello');
fdata.append('c[]', 'world');
fdata.append('c[]', '!');
```

After setting the form data instance, you can use it as the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, as stated, creating the `FormData` manually will not make it as dynamic as I want. I've found the answer, will create a new answer :)

Comment: I don't understand the level of dynamism you were trying to achieve. Actually, the query-string solution is far worse as it has length limitations and it is not feasible to send large amounts of data.

Comment: Although, you are not using the URL encoded string as a query string but as a post body so there should be no lengths limitations.

Comment: yea, you are right. It is not a `URL encoded string`, but a `serialized string` representation. Changed that. So the dynamism is was going for, is that I don't have worry about all the values inside the object itself. Imagine having a big object, then placing every variable manually into the `FormData` would be a pain. I cannot find any drawbacks using `$.param` in the body as of right now.